# importing python modules that have a . in the name of the directory

Tags: python

I have a directory called my.directory and a file in it called file.py, I need to write a python script that uses file.py and I cannot change the names of the files or directories, moreover the script cannot be in the same directory as file.py. I have tried this:

```
import my.directory.file
```

and this

```
import my\.directory.file
```

neither of which work, I would like to know if this is possible and if so how.

Thanks

edit:

I phrased the above question in a general way because I didn't think the particular details of the problem were important however here are the details anyway. I'm trying to import from python3.6/site-packages

Comment: Why can’t you change the names of the files or directories? Do you actually need it as a module, or as a script?

Comment: I need to import a module that I downloaded, I can't change the names of the directories because there are other scripts dependent on it and I don't want to have to change them all

Comment: If you can't move the module to a place python is aware of, instead make python aware of the location of the module.  The easiest way is probably to update your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Read more about how how modules are imported [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: python3.6/site-packages? Is this a venv?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a dot in the module or package name under Python.

But you can execute any arbitrary python code dynamically under your namespace by doing::

```
>>> exec(open("my.directory.file").read())
```

Comment: does running the __init__ file have the same effect as importing ?

Comment: only if the ``init`` initialise the rest of the package, i.e. it imports the sibling modules, otherwise no.